# Are there public repos including WordPress WooCommerce and CiviCRM integration code?

Tags: api, wordpress, civicontribute, woocommerce

On a WordPress / CiviCRM installation, we need to do a bunch of customization on its payment pages. We want to do it in WordPress since there are WordPress plugins that can help do things like validate addresses and calculate sales taxes that are not yet available in CiviCRM, and the budget is constrained. The main integration we want is to write to CiviCRM 1) contact info, 2) invoice data for memberships, participants, and 'contribution' items like book purchases, and 3) payments received.

We're going to start by upgrading the CiviCRM API to allow multiple line items including Sales Taxes to be added properly.

Is there a good starting repo for the WordPress plugin anywhere? I've contacted Josh at http://www.joshcanhelp.com/wordpress-ecommerce-site-integrated-civicrm-migrated-drupal-6/#comment-30644. Alternatively, custom non-generalized implementations would also be fine.

Comment: perhaps this question belongs on the wordpress stackexchange?

Comment: good suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't seem like there is a public repo that has code integrating wooCommerce and CiviCRM yet.

Comment: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/9343/26

Answer (score 3):

For those interested there is a great start...[blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/parvez/woocommerce-integration) with code here: [github](https://github.com/veda-consulting/woocommerce_civicrm)

Answer (score 2):

I currently have a project in which we will be integrating CiviCRM with WooCommerce.  I have also contacted Josh to see if we could perhaps put our heads together to come up with some sort of common solution that others may be able to use.  Will keep you posted.

Comment: Parvez at Veda Consulting is looking to do some stuff here and is in contact with a few other like minded shops. I'm going to put him in touch with another provider on the project I am on who is going to be doing a quickish set of calls to new API JMA is putting together for orders and payments for 4.7 core. Could you contact me @ joe dot murray at jmaconsulting dot biz ? Thanks @Interpolat

Comment: I've sent you an email.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you mean by "a starting point for the Wordpress plugin", but I'd start by triggering the appropriate CiviCRM API calls when various [WooCommerce hooks](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) are fired. [Hello Dolly](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/) is a good reference point to start a Wordpress plugin from.