# wordpress woocommerce + civicrm integration points

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, integration

I'm looking at wordpress + woocommerce + civicrm for a client.  I'm quite familiar with all three, however not sure how they could best be integrated.

Client is considering woocommerce for selling subscriptions, which creates a wordpress user profile + order record(s).  One issue is extending the checkout process to include additional wordpress profile fields (like birthday) which is simple enough.  Civicrm can "sync" with wordpress users, but does anyone have a best practice for managing extended profiles?  Woocommerce is expecting certain customer fields so we can't simply replace the profile with a civicrm profile.

---

As a side note, we will likely need to extract subscriber / order info as it will contain things like donations.  subscriber status can be opined by keeping the roles->civicrm groups in sync.

---

I'm wondering if there is a way to extend the civicrm+WP sync process to include more wordpress profile fields and thereby keeping info in sync.  Perhaps duplicating the collection of info during checkout is another approach.

I've not done a civi+wp implementation before (but am very familiar with each) so I may be making some silly assumptions.  Also, trying to approach this as a system builder without requiring too much custom code.

Any approaches/references welcome.  I expect there will be increasing interest in integrating info from WP+Woo+Civicrm as it is the leading WP ecomm solution.

Comment: There is another open question on these 3 technologies here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25/are-there-public-repos-including-wordpress-woocommerce-and-civicrm-integration-c?rq=1